# jQuery - click change parent and other div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this situation: jsfiddle.net/T8NZc/

And i want make, when clicked on div colour change div=row height (parent) and div=desc. How I can make this?

Comment: I didn't really understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you re-word the question? This is very hard to figure out based on what you asked.

Comment: I feel like there should be an English pre-test for Stack

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.colour').click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent...//do something
    parent.find('.desc')...//do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var parentHgt = $('.row').height() + $('.data').height() + $('.desc').height();
    // or take out the height value in CSS and use the parent's outer height
    // var parentHgt = $('.row').outerHeight();
    $('.colour').click(function () {
        $(this).css({
            'background': '#ccc',
            'height': parentHgt + 'px',
        });
        $(this).text($('.desc').html());
    });
```

**[Here's the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T8NZc/13/)**.